# How to remove border inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, jscrollpane

Hello are there ways to remove the border header inside JScrollPane?

Here is the picture of my JScrollPane header border
[image: Remove the ugly inside header border]

I tried many ways to remove the header border like including setting border to null, but no success.

Here is the code that set the JScrollPane border...

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new CustomJScrollBar());
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    scrollPane.setBounds(105, 127, 1120, 540);
    scrollPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    add(scrollPane);
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need to augment the default cell header renderer, e.g.:

```
public class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private TableCellRenderer parent;
    private Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();

    private MyRenderer(TableCellRenderer parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JLabel headerLabel = (JLabel) parent.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        headerLabel.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        return headerLabel;
    }
}
```

Then, you would set this as the renderer to use with:

```
JTable jt = <your table>
JTableHeader tableHeader = jt.getTableHeader();
tableHeader.setDefaultRenderer(new MyRenderer(tableHeader.getDefaultRenderer()));
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 0
 at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Unknown Source) The error is at (JTableHeader) scrollPane.getColumnHeader().getComponent(0);

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming you use a JTable as the underlying component, maybe it's better to set the renderer directly on this with:         JTableHeader tableHeader = jt.getTableHeader();
        tableHeader.setDefaultRenderer(new MyRenderer(tableHeader.getDefaultRenderer())); (answer updated)